# Yii2 components overriding constructor conventions

Tags: php, constructor, yii2, constructor-injection

I looked at the Yii 2 manual for [components](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-components.html) and I don't get why there are two conflicting conventions or possibly an anti-pattern. Manual says:

> Always call the parent constructor at the end of your overriding constructor.
>
> If you override the yii\base\Object::init() method, make sure you call the parent implementation of init at the beginning of your init method.

About the first convention my [argument is that](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/), the parent constructor should be invoked first , even better it should not depend on the order of these statements .

I know Yii does not strictly follows design-patterns and principles but uses enough to make it faster. What is your thought on this ? Correct me if I am wrong.